# Flutter JSON The class doesn't have a constructor named 'fromJson'

Tags: json, flutter, constructor

can anyone explain me why this code doenst work?

I have two classes

IngredientEntry.dart

```
import 'package:CoolKiosk/MasterData/ingredient.dart';
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

class IngredientEntry {
  Decimal addOnPrice;
  Ingredient ingredient;

  IngredientEntry(Decimal addOnPrice, Ingredient ingredient) {
    this.addOnPrice = addOnPrice;
    this.ingredient = ingredient;
  }

  factory IngredientEntry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var _addOnPrice = Decimal.parse(json['price'].toString());
    var _ingredient = Ingredient.fromJson(json['ingredient']);

    return new IngredientEntry(_addOnPrice, _ingredient);
  }
}
```

and class IngredientGroup.dart

```
import 'package:CoolKiosk/CustomWidget/IngredientEntry.dart';
import 'package:CoolKiosk/MasterData/base_object.dart';

class IngredientGroup extends BaseObject {
  String networkId;
  String satelliteId;
  String name;
  int minSelection;
  int maxSelection;
  int includedItems;

  List<IngredientEntry> ingredientEntries = new List<IngredientEntry>();

  IngredientGroup(String id, String networkId, String satelliteId, String name,
      int minSel, int maxSel, int includedItems)
      : super(id) {
    this.networkId = networkId;
    this.satelliteId = satelliteId;
    this.name = name;
    this.minSelection = minSel;
    this.maxSelection = maxSel;
    this.includedItems = includedItems;
  }

  factory IngredientGroup.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var _id = json['_id'];
    var _networkId = json['networkId'];
    var _satelliteId = json['satelliteId'];
    var _name = json['name'];
    var _minSelection = json['minSelection'];
    var _maxSelection = json['maxSelection'];
    var _includedItems = json['includedItems'];

    IngredientGroup ingredientGroup = new IngredientGroup(_id, _networkId,
        _satelliteId, _name, _minSelection, _maxSelection, _includedItems);

    final _ingredientEntryList = json['ingredientEntries'];
    for (var i = 0; i < _ingredientEntryList.length; i++) {
      ingredientGroup.ingredientEntries
          .add(new IngredientEntry.fromJson(_ingredientEntryList[i]));
    }

    return ingredientGroup;
  }
}
```

class Ingredient.dart

```
import 'package:CoolKiosk/MasterData/base_object.dart';
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

class Ingredient extends BaseObject {
  String networkId;
  String satelliteId;
  String name;
  Decimal addOnPrice;
  Decimal downPrice;

  Ingredient(String id, String networkId, String satelliteId, String name,
      Decimal addOnPrice, Decimal downPrice)
      : super(id) {
    this.networkId = networkId;
    this.satelliteId = satelliteId;
    this.name = name;
    this.addOnPrice = addOnPrice;
    this.downPrice = downPrice;
  }

  factory Ingredient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var _id = json['_id'];
    var _networkId = json['networkId'];
    var _satelliteId = json['satelliteId'];
    var _name = json['name'];
    var _addOnPrice = Decimal.parse(json['addOnPrice'].toString());
    var _downPrice = Decimal.parse(json['downPrice'].toString());

    return Ingredient(
        _id, _networkId, _satelliteId, _name, _addOnPrice, _downPrice);
  }
}
```

The part IngredientEntry.fromJson failes with the following error:
*The class 'IngredientEntry' doesn't have a constructor named 'fromJson'.
Try invoking a different constructor, or define a constructor named 'fromJson'.dart(new_with_undefined_constructor)*

I do not understand what im doing wrong.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: did you find any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Ingredient class does not have factory method. Can you edit that into the question as well?

Comment: I edited the question - in my opinion the Ingredient class should be ok

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes arround this question,

the coude aboce should run fine. My mistake was outside of this snipped, i had a class and a widget named IngredientEntry.